# Mongoose - Delete property from SubDocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I have the following Mongoose schema and code:

Schema:

```
{
    ...
    inv: {
        type: Object,
        default: {}
    },
    ...
}
```

---

Code (version 1), where `targetData` is a Mongoose `Document`, `item` is a `String`, and `amount` is a `Number`:

```
targetData.inv[item] = targetData.inv[item] - amount;
if (!targetData.inv[item]) delete targetData.inv[item];
await targetData.save();
```

---

Code (version 2):

```
targetData.inv[item] = targetData.inv[item] - amount;
if (!targetData.inv[item]) targetData.inv[item] = undefined;
await targetData.save();
```

---

The problem is that neither of these attempts removes `targetData.inv[item]` from the Document. My goal is to remove an item, say `"thing"`, from a SubDocument. For example:

Before:

```
{
    ...
    inv: {
        thing: 5
    },
    ...
}
```

---

After:

```
{
    ...
    inv: {},
    ...
}
```

---

Note: When `amount` is a number less than `5` (in the above example), the code works fine. If I'm removing all `5`, that's when it doesn't update, it would stay as `5`.

Note 2: I'm using Mongoose 5.3.15

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Looks like this only happens if `inv` only has 1 property. Having something like `inv: { thing: 5, anotherThing: 6 }` will work perfectly with the `delete` keyword.

Comment: What is the actual condition to remove the property? Is it that when a value is less than or equal to `0` then delete?

Comment: @chridam Specifically `0`, yes

Comment: Have you tried using the [`set()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set) method: ``if (targetData.inv[item] === 0) targetData.set(`inv.${item}`, undefined, {strict: false} );``?

Comment: @chridam Interesting, this works. Would you be able to explain why this works instead of my other attempts in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: @chridam Update: If `inv` has multiple properties, using `set()` will set as `null`, even if I provide `undefined`. So this only works if `inv` has one property...

Comment: @drinchev 5.3.15

Comment: @apxx latest is 5.4.1 ( https://mongoosejs.com ) Are you sure? Your code works ( at least the part with `delete item.inv.foo`. It simply assigns `null` to the value in the mongo database. Anyway `const item = new Item( { inv : { foo : "bar" } } ); item.save().then( item => { console.log( item ); delete item.inv.foo; item.save().then( item => { console.log( item ); } ); } );`

Comment: @drinchev Sorry, checked wrong thing, I'm on 5.3.15

Comment: @apxx Works as well. https://gist.github.com/drinchev/9957a01d1db60c3cf4cdeb8a17e20fd1 . This is my code.

Comment: @drinchev This is strange... Here's what I tried and its output https://hastebin.com/yaqukupipa.js - Something isn't right here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. All I needed to do was manually tell Mongoose that `inv` has been modified, using `targetData.markModified("inv")`. [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified). This is due to the SchemaType being [Mixed (`Object`)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you solved the issue but I have an idea. 
Normally in this situation, I would like to get the document and go through the object and find the item and remove it and save the document again. It is a naive way that I'm doing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. Do you have an example?